# Solution for convert SQL to XSLT

Tags: sql, xslt, converters

Now i working with very specific problem:
I have some SQL rules like

```
case when ((#variable1#=10) and (#variable2# in (10,11)) or (#variable3#>12) ... other conditions... then 1 else 0
```

where #variable# is markers for replace on real values in runtime
and i need to translate this rules in XSLT. I found in internet some publications about that
like http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/ratul/papers/www2002-xslt.pdf
and my question now: may be anyone know about open source solution for convert sql to xslt or back?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few:

- [EasySQL](http://search.cpan.org/~curtisf/XML-EasySQL-1.2/)
- [XML-SQL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xml-sql/)
- [XML2DDL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xml2ddl/0.3.1)